# Парсинг JSON: вытащить значения "value" во всех "type: Number"

Tags: python, dict

Как отсюда можно вытащить значения "value" во всех "type: Number"?

```
{
  "string": "сколько будет 2 прибавить два ?",
  "tokens": [
    {
      "type": "Text",
      "substring": "сколько будет",
      "value": "сколько будет"
    },
    {
      "type": "Number",
      "substring": "2",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "Text",
      "substring": "прибавить",
      "value": "прибавить"
    },
    {
      "type": "Number",
      "substring": "два",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "Text",
      "substring": "?",
      "value": "?"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Как вы пробовали и что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Элементарным циклом можно

Comment: `[x['value'] for x in вашжсон['tokens'] if x['type'] == 'Number']`

Comment: `jq '.tokens[] | select(.type=="Number") | .value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

jsonString = '{"string":"сколько будет 2 прибавить два ?","tokens":[{"type":"Text","substring":"сколько будет","value":"сколько будет"},{"type":"Number","substring":"2","value":2},{"type":"Text","substring":"прибавить","value":"прибавить"},{"type":"Number","substring":"два","value":2},{"type":"Text","substring":"?","value":"?"}]}'
arr = json.loads(jsonString)
result = []
for item in arr['tokens']:
  if item['type'] == 'Number':
    result.append(item['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

С использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

res = (pd.DataFrame(json.loads(jstring)['tokens'])
         .query("type=='Number'")['value']
         .tolist())
```

Результат:

```
In [151]: print(res)
[2, 2]
```